# How can I list.append("") after looping and one condition was not met?

Tags: python, list, loops

#### Create Lists

each list is a different category

```
a=[]
b=[]
c=[]
d=[]
e=[]
f=[]
words=['a ','b ','c ','d ','e ','f ']
det =['b low','c high','f light','e dark']
```

I have these letters(words) that i want to remove from det, and after that I want to append each det to the corresponding letter list but if there isn't any correspondence to those words, .append('')

I know i can just put at the end to append '' to the list that don't have elements, but this iteration is for a 'det' that will be changing and appending more and more values to the different lists

#### Here is the code till now:

```
i= 0
for x in det:
    if words[0] in x:
        a.append(x.replace(words[0],""))
        i+=1
    elif words[1] in x:
        b.append(x.replace(words[1],""))
        i+=1
    elif words[2] in x:
        c.append(x.replace(words[2],""))
        i+=1
    elif words[3] in x:
        d.append(x.replace(words[3],""))
        i+=1
    elif words[4] in x:
        e.append(x.replace(words[4],""))
        i+=1
    elif words[5] in x:
        f.append(x.replace(words[5],""))
        i+=1
```

###### The end result would be something like this after 2 different 'det':

where the second 'det' would be:

```
det =['a letter','c high','d apple','f light']
```

end result:

```
a = ['','letter']
b = ['low','']
c = ['high','high']
d = ['','apple']
e = ['dark','']
f = ['light','light']
```

Comment: Your code is not reproducible

Comment: Where did "apple" come from? It isn't really clear what you're after; to me at least.

Comment: try to run everything, not only the "here is the code" part

Comment: @theherk each list is a different category. the second result of each list would be a different 'det'(with different words)

Comment: There are words in your solution that do not exist in your initial list. How did they appear ? Also, why are words reproduced twice sometimes ?

Comment: @Afonseca ok, you should have mentioned the varying "det", are your string always formatted like `"x yyyy"`? can the id be more than one letter? etc.

Comment: @ApplePie I edited the post, you should be able to understand now

Comment: @mozway the format is always like that , and the id it's only those letters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach. I am using dictionaries to perform the matches and to store the output:

```
words=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

det1 = ['b low', 'c high', 'f light', 'e dark']
det2 = ['a letter', 'c high', 'd apple', 'f light']

out = {k: [] for k in words}

# loop over det occurrences
for det in [det1, det2]:
    # create dictionary to match the ids
    # in the form: {'b': 'low', 'c': 'high'...}
    det_dic = {(x:=e.split(' ', 1))[0]: x[1] for e in det}

    # for each key, append match if existing else ''
    for k,v in out.items():
        v.append(det_dic.get(k, ''))
```

output:

```
>>> out
{'a': ['', 'letter'],
 'b': ['low', ''],
 'c': ['high', 'high'],
 'd': ['', 'apple'],
 'e': ['dark', ''],
 'f': ['light', 'light']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code should work

```py
words=['a','b','c','d','e','f']
det =['b low','c high','f light','e dark']

data = {letter: [] for letter in words}

for x in det: # for each item in det
    for y in words: # for each item in words
        if x.startswith(y): # if the det starts with letter
            data[y].append(x.replace(y,"").strip()) # data[*letter*] will be appended with *det* item 
        else:
            data[y].append("")
print(data)
```

this will output *(after the 1st `det`)*

```py
[('a', ['', '', '', '']),
 ('b', ['low', '', '', '']),
 ('c', ['', 'high', '', '']),
 ('d', ['', '', '', '']),
 ('e', ['', '', '', 'dark']),
 ('f', ['', '', 'light', ''])])
```

now let me explain it:

- Firstly I removed the trailing space from the letters in `words`
- then instead of initializing static empty lists, we would initialize
  a dictionary `data` with (`words`) letters as *keys*, and *values* of
  empty lists, this was done using `data = {word: [] for word in words}` line
- next we would iterate over both lists to append the list values in the `data` dictionary.

note that in `if x.startswith(y):` we used `startswith()` to ensure the det items starts with the corresponding letter

and in `data[y].append(x.replace(y,"").strip())` we used `strip()` to remove the trailing space after the first letter